# A Question on continuity of a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

I wanted to know, how to check the continuity at $(0,0)$ of the following function:

$
 f(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
  \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3} & \text{$x^3+y^3\ne0$}\\
  0                        & \text{$x^3+y^3=  0$}\\
 \end{cases}
$

I have never tried a question like this.

All the questions I have done up until now have always been homogenous.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to compute limits in two variables?

Comment: @PenasRaul in all the q's i did, i substituted x=ky^c for some k,c and the equation got rid of x and y but here it does not, is there any other method?

Comment: What do the brackets "[" and "]" ?

Comment: @georg nothing in particular

Comment: @downvoter mind telling me what to add to improve this post

Comment: This one is also homogeneous, but of degree $1$ rather than $0$. Namely, $f(tx,ty)=t^1 f(x,y)$. Useful fact: if a function is continuous outside of $(0,0)$ and is homogeneous of degree $>0$, then its limit at $(0,0)$ is $0$.

Comment: @Thursday thank u for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that $x^3$ and $y^3$ can assume both signs, hence (almost) cancel without being small. That is, if $y\approx -x$ then the denominator is $\approx 0$ whereas the numerator is $\approx x^4$. So we should try to turn the $\approx 0$ into something comparable with $x^4$
One can try somethig like $y=-x+x^2$. Then $y^3=-x^3+3x^4-3x^5+x^6$. You may thus verify that
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} f(t,-t+t^2)=\frac13\ne f(0,0)$$